# Is it possible to have optional DataMembers in WCF?

Tags: wcf

If I have the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class GetColorsRS
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Colors", Order = 0, IsRequired=true)]
    public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Errors", Order = 1, IsRequired=false)]
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

If no errors are found in the request, I want to send back a response that does not have an Errors node, however, it passes back an Errors node that is empty.  I thought this is what the IsRequired was for?

Just noticed EmitDefaultValue, is this what I am looking for?

Comment: Why not just have an empty list of errors?? Basically achieves the same thing (without any messy hacks or tricks) ??

Comment: @marc_s, I can do that too.  But setting EmitDefaultValue = false is hardly a hack or messy trick.

Comment: Be careful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382402/why-is-using-datamemberemitdefaultvalue-false-not-recommended

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have determined that `EmitDefaultValue` should be set to false if I don't want to serialize the default value of the DataMember.

```
 [DataMember(Name = "Errors", Order = 1, IsRequired=false,EmitDefaultValue=false)]
 public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
```