# how to WCF dynamic DataMember?

Tags: json, wcf, datacontract, datamember

example: a Customer class have 100 data member(id, name, age, address...etc)  to be serialization to JSON.

In Config file such as Web.config, can set a output list to serialize JSON ouptut.

If output only id and name, then JSON only have id and name.

My Question: **Can support dynamic DataMember in a DataContract ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean optional datamembers, I guess so, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257590/is-it-possible-to-have-optional-datamembers-in-wcf)
Surely you'll have to have null values for  the ones you dont want to send over the wire.
Another, more dirtier, solution would be to use a dictionary as a datamember and have the fields you want to send as elements there. There may be type conversion issues, but maybe it serves you better.

**Edit:**

You probably want to go with a dictioray serialized as an associative array en js, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861138/c-sharp-json-serialization-of-dictionary-into-keyvalue-instead-of-keyk) specifies. Check the answers and the links in there. That should get you going.
But still I'd go with optional datamembers since it's more of a "contract" thing. Other than that a better description of what you want to do will help.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but i guess you should try with a dictionary as the only datamember and serialize that as json. I've updated my answer with the relevant link.