# Is it possible to use EmitDefaultValue 'sometimes' using the DataContractSerializer in .NET?

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

Is there any way to conditionally specify [EmitDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) at runtime for the DataContractSerializer in .NET?  Are there any workarounds?

For example, I am curious whether I could use EmitDefaultValue=false for WCF serialization, but I would like to be able to use EmitDefaultValue=true for XMLs generated for external interfaces, such as print.

Comment: Is the XML using XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer? (it matters)

Comment: Specifically, IIRC: DCS supports \*Specified, and XS supports both \*Specified and ShouldSerialize\* (for conditional serialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, two options you potentially have are to use a [data contract surrogate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/14/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates.aspx) or an [IObjectReference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/27/wcf-extensibility-other-serialization-extensions.aspx). I think both of these are overkill for you, but if you really, really want to support this scenario on your end, maybe this is a sacrifice you're willing to make. Note that using them also has significant implications for performance, interoperability, exposure via schema, etc.

I also want to point out that what you're trying to do -- EmitDefaultValue of false -- is not recommended for a number of reasons, even though I know what the common motivations are. See [Why is using [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)] not recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382402/why-is-using-datamemberemitdefaultvalue-false-not-recommended)

Comment: Interesting.  I'll check out the IObjectReference.  I had briefly looked into the Data Contract Surrogate.  I tend to agree that using EmitDefaultValue = false is hiding some other design flaw such as an overly bloated object structure.  In this situation the only external interface to these serialized objects is print.